# Google Developers Console - differences in reported Datastore stored data quantities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In our GAE apps I have discovered that there are differences in the reported Datastore Stored Data quantities.

In one of apps at the GAE Dashboard (https://console.developers.google.com/project/{PROJECT_ID}/appengine) "Datastore Stored Data" usage shows: **30.37GB**. At the main dashboard of our project (https://console.developers.google.com/project/{PROJECT_ID}) Resources -> Storage -> Cloud Datastore it shows **6.84GB**.

Why there is a difference?

**EDIT:**

GAE Dashboard:
[image: GAE Dashboard]

Datastore Dashboard:
[image: Datastore Dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

The number you see from the main page seems to be numbering the amount of entities your have, and their sizes.

The other (bigger number) is the full size of your datastore data, which includes metadata.

I would guess that if you go to "Storage->Datastore->Dashboard", you will see your entities + indexes totaling 6,84GB, and metadata being around 23 GB. I'm pretty convinces that the "storage->Datastore->Dashboard" page will provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Under "storage->Datastore->Dashboard" the "Metadata" is 480MB, so it looks like is about something else.

Comment: @adampawluczuk do you mind editing the screenshots in your  question? I'll try to see what I can figure out